# Matching boost::deadline_timer callbacks to corresponding wait_async

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Consider this short code snippet where one boost::deadline_timer interrupts another:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

static boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer1(io);
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer2(io);

static void timer1_handler1(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " time:" << time(0) << " error:" << error.message() << " expect:Operation canceled." << std::endl;        
}        

static void timer1_handler2(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " time:" << time(0) << " error:" << error.message() << " expect:success." << std::endl;        
}        

static void timer2_handler1(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " time:" << time(0) << " error:" << error.message() << " expect:success." << std::endl;        
    std::cout << "cancel and restart timer1. Bind to timer1_handler2" << std::endl;
    timer1.cancel();
    timer1.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10000));
    timer1.async_wait(boost::bind(timer1_handler2, boost::asio::placeholders::error));        
}        

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start timer1. Bind to timer1_handler1." << std::endl;
    timer1.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(2000));
    timer1.async_wait(boost::bind(timer1_handler1, boost::asio::placeholders::error));        

    std::cout << "Start timer2. Bind to timer2_handler1. Will interrupt timer1." << std::endl;
    timer2.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(2000));
    timer2.async_wait(boost::bind(timer2_handler1, boost::asio::placeholders::error));        

    std::cout << "Run the boost io service." << std::endl;
    io.run();

    return 0;
}
```

If the time for timer2 is varied around the 2 second mark, sometimes timer1_handler1 reports success, and sometimes operation cancelled. This is probably determinate in the trivial example because we know what time timer2 is set to.

```
./timer1
Start timer1. Bind to timer1_handler1.
Start timer2. Bind to timer2_handler1. Will interrupt timer1.
Run the boost io service.
void timer1_handler1(const boost::system::error_code&) time:1412680360 error:Success expect:Operation canceled.
void timer2_handler1(const boost::system::error_code&) time:1412680360 error:Success expect:success.
cancel and restart timer1. Bind to timer1_handler2
void timer1_handler2(const boost::system::error_code&) time:1412680370 error:Success expect:success.
```

This represents a more complex system where timer1 is implementing a timeout, and timer2 is really an asynchronous socket. Occasionally I've observed a scenario where timer1 is cancelled too late, and the first handler returns after the second async_wait() has been called, thus giving a spurious timeout.

Clearly I need to match up the handler callbacks with the corresponding async_wait() call. Is there a convenient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `boost::bind` additional parameters to the completion handler which can be used to identify the source.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. In reality async_wait() is called many times, so do I need some kind of state variable that gets incremented each time? Is the extra bound variable bound by reference or bound by value, or does it depend on how you define the bind?

Comment: @SimonElliott It's up to you. You can even elect to pass a reference to the service object (such as `deadline_timer`) with `boost::ref(timer1)`. Note: "async_wait()" is called many times? You can't, however, have multiple async operations in progress on the same object (socket, timer). You'd need to cancel the pending operation (`timer1.expires_from_now()`)  or sequence the operations (using `strand`s or perhaps a coroutine)

Answer (score 5):

One convenient way of solving the posed problem, managing higher-level asynchronous operations composed of multiple non-chained asynchronous operations, is by using the approach used in the official Boost [timeout](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp) example.  Within it, handlers make decisions by examining current state, rather than coupling handler logic with an expected or provided state.

Before working on a solution, it is important to identify all possible cases of handler execution.  When the `io_service` is ran, a single iteration of the event loop will execute all operations that are ready to run, and upon completion of the operation, the user's completion handler is queued with an `error_code` indicating the operation's status.  The `io_service` will then invoke the queued completion handlers.  Hence, in a single iteration, all ready to run operations are executed in an unspecified order before completion handlers, and the order in which completion handlers are invoked is unspecified.  For instance, when composing an `async_read_with_timeout()` operation from `async_read()` and `async_wait()`, where either operation is only cancelled within the other operation's completion handler, the following case are possible:

- `async_read()` runs and `async_wait()` is not ready to run, then  `async_read()`'s completion handler is invoked and cancels `async_wait()`, causing `async_wait()`'s completion handler to run with an error of `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`.
- `async_read()` is not ready to run and `async_wait()` runs, then `async_wait()`'s completion handler is invoked and cancels `async_read()`, causing `async_read()`'s completion handler to run with an error of `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`.
- `async_read()` and `async_wait()` run, then `async_read()`'s completion handler is invoked first, but the `async_wait()` operation has already completed and cannot be cancelled, so `async_wait()`'s completion handler will run with no error.
- `async_read()` and `async_wait()` run, then `async_wait()`'s completion handler is invoked first, but the `async_read()` operation has already completed and cannot be cancelled, so `async_read()`'s completion handler will run with no error.

The completion handler's `error_code` indicates the status of the operation and does not not reflect changes in state resulting from other completion handlers; therefore, when the `error_code` is successful, one may need examine the current state to perform conditional branching.  However, before introducing additional state, it can be worth taking the effort to examine the goal of the higher-level operation and what state is already available.  For this example, lets define that the goal of `async_read_with_timeout()` is to close a socket if data has not been received before a deadline has been reached.  For state, the socket is either open or closed; the timer provides expiration time; and the system clock provides the current time.  After examining the goal and available state information, one may propose that:

- `async_wait()`'s handler should only close the socket if the timer's current expiration time is in the past.
- `async_read()`'s handler should set the timer's expiration time into the future.

With that approach, if `async_read()`'s completion handler runs before `async_wait()`, then either `async_wait()` will be cancelled or `async_wait()`'s completion handler will not close the connection, as the current expiration time is in the future.  On the other hand, if `async_wait()`'s completion handler runs before `async_read()`, then either `async_read()` will be cancelled or `async_read()`'s completion handler can detect that the socket is closed.

Here is a complete minimal example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/446c66ea5ab4c277) this approach for various use cases:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class client
{
public:

  // This demo is only using status for asserting code paths.  It is not
  // necessary nor should it be used for conditional branching.
  enum status_type
  {
    unknown,
    timeout,
    read_success,
    read_failure
  };

public:

  client(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket)
    : strand_(socket.get_io_service()),
      timer_(socket.get_io_service()),
      socket_(socket),
      status_(unknown)
  {}

  status_type status() const { return status_; }

  void async_read_with_timeout(boost::posix_time::seconds seconds)
  {
    strand_.post(boost::bind(
        &client::do_async_read_with_timeout, this, seconds));
  }

private:

  void do_async_read_with_timeout(boost::posix_time::seconds seconds)
  {
    // Start a timeout for the read.
    timer_.expires_from_now(seconds);
    timer_.async_wait(strand_.wrap(boost::bind(
        &client::handle_wait, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error)));

    // Start the read operation.
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_,  
        boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
        strand_.wrap(boost::bind(
          &client::handle_read, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
  }

  void handle_wait(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    // On error, such as cancellation, return early.
    if (error)
    {
      std::cout << "timeout cancelled" << std::endl;
      return;
    }

    // The timer may have expired, but it is possible that handle_read()
    // ran succesfully and updated the timer's expiration:
    // - a new timeout has been started.  For example, handle_read() ran and
    //   invoked do_async_read_with_timeout().
    // - there are no pending timeout reads.  For example, handle_read() ran
    //   but did not invoke do_async_read_with_timeout();
    if (timer_.expires_at() > boost::asio::deadline_timer::traits_type::now())
    {
      std::cout << "timeout occured, but handle_read ran first" << std::endl;
      return;
    }

    // Otherwise, a timeout has occured and handle_read() has not executed, so
    // close the socket, cancelling the read operation.
    std::cout << "timeout occured" << std::endl;
    status_ = client::timeout;
    boost::system::error_code ignored_ec;
    socket_.close(ignored_ec);
  }

  void handle_read(
    const boost::system::error_code& error,
    std::size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    // Update timeout state to indicate handle_read() has ran.  This
    // cancels any pending timeouts.
    timer_.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);

    // On error, return early.
    if (error)
    {
      std::cout << "read failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
      // Only set status if it is unknown.
      if (client::unknown == status_) status_ = client::read_failure;
      return;
    }

    // The read was succesful, but if a timeout occured and handle_wait()
    // ran first, then the socket is closed, so return early.
    if (!socket_.is_open())
    {
      std::cout << "read was succesful but timeout occured" << std::endl;
      return;
    }

    std::cout << "read was succesful" << std::endl;
    status_ = client::read_success;
  }

private:

  boost::asio::io_service::strand strand_;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket_;
  char buffer_[1];
  status_type status_;
};

// This example is not interested in the connect handlers, so provide a noop
// function that will be passed to bind to meet the handler concept
// requirements.
void noop() {}

/// @brief Create a connection between the server and client socket.
void connect_sockets(
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor& acceptor,
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& server_socket,
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& client_socket)
{
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service = acceptor.get_io_service();
  acceptor.async_accept(server_socket, boost::bind(&noop));
  client_socket.async_connect(acceptor.local_endpoint(), boost::bind(&noop));
  io_service.reset();
  io_service.run();
  io_service.reset();
}

int main()
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 0));

  // Scenario 1: timeout
  // The server writes no data, causing a client timeout to occur.
  {
    std::cout << "[Scenario 1: timeout]" << std::endl;
    // Create and connect I/O objects.
    tcp::socket server_socket(io_service);
    tcp::socket client_socket(io_service);
    connect_sockets(acceptor, server_socket, client_socket);

    // Start read with timeout on client.
    client client(client_socket);
    client.async_read_with_timeout(boost::posix_time::seconds(0));

    // Allow do_read_with_timeout to intiate actual operations.
    io_service.run_one();    

    // Run timeout and read operations.
    io_service.run();
    assert(client.status() == client::timeout);
  }

  // Scenario 2: no timeout, succesful read
  // The server writes data and the io_service is ran before the timer 
  // expires.  In this case, the async_read operation will complete and
  // cancel the async_wait.
  {
    std::cout << "[Scenario 2: no timeout, succesful read]" << std::endl;
    // Create and connect I/O objects.
    tcp::socket server_socket(io_service);
    tcp::socket client_socket(io_service);
    connect_sockets(acceptor, server_socket, client_socket);

    // Start read with timeout on client.
    client client(client_socket);
    client.async_read_with_timeout(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));

    // Allow do_read_with_timeout to intiate actual operations.
    io_service.run_one();

    // Write to client.
    boost::asio::write(server_socket, boost::asio::buffer("test"));

    // Run timeout and read operations.
    io_service.run();
    assert(client.status() == client::read_success);
  }

  // Scenario 3: no timeout, failed read
  // The server closes the connection before the timeout, causing the
  // async_read operation to fail and cancel the async_wait operation.
  {
    std::cout << "[Scenario 3: no timeout, failed read]" << std::endl;
    // Create and connect I/O objects.
    tcp::socket server_socket(io_service);
    tcp::socket client_socket(io_service);
    connect_sockets(acceptor, server_socket, client_socket);

    // Start read with timeout on client.
    client client(client_socket);
    client.async_read_with_timeout(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));

    // Allow do_read_with_timeout to intiate actual operations.
    io_service.run_one();

    // Close the socket.
    server_socket.close();

    // Run timeout and read operations.
    io_service.run();
    assert(client.status() == client::read_failure);
  }

  // Scenario 4: timeout and read success
  // The server writes data, but the io_service is not ran until the
  // timer has had time to expire.  In this case, both the await_wait and
  // asnyc_read operations complete, but the order in which the
  // handlers run is indeterminiate.
  {
    std::cout << "[Scenario 4: timeout and read success]" << std::endl;
    // Create and connect I/O objects.
    tcp::socket server_socket(io_service);
    tcp::socket client_socket(io_service);
    connect_sockets(acceptor, server_socket, client_socket);

    // Start read with timeout on client.
    client client(client_socket);
    client.async_read_with_timeout(boost::posix_time::seconds(0));

    // Allow do_read_with_timeout to intiate actual operations.
    io_service.run_one();

    // Allow the timeout to expire, the write to the client, causing both
    // operations to complete with success.
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
    boost::asio::write(server_socket, boost::asio::buffer("test"));

    // Run timeout and read operations.
    io_service.run();
    assert(   (client.status() == client::timeout)
           || (client.status() == client::read_success));
  }
}
```

And its output:

```
[Scenario 1: timeout]
timeout occured
read failed: Operation canceled
[Scenario 2: no timeout, succesful read]
read was succesful
timeout cancelled
[Scenario 3: no timeout, failed read]
read failed: End of file
timeout cancelled
[Scenario 4: timeout and read success]
read was succesful
timeout occured, but handle_read ran first
```

Comment: Nice detailed answer. I wonder if this type of strategy could be used to implement a generic "operation-with-a-timeout" mechanism that is easily wrapped around existing operations that ASIO provides. I know that I've wanted that often before and end up reinventing it multiple times.

Comment: @JasonR With the current implementation, generic timeout mechanisms are possible.  However, in my experience, they often have far more of a negative impact on the quality of application code than benefits for my taste.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed response. I did see the boost example you linked, but misunderstood what the deadline timer check was all about. I prefer this approach to the alternative of maintaining timer state.